# DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL). How to wrap in Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have this query:

```
@members = Member.where("EXTRACT(DOY FROM date_of_birth) >= ?", next_bdays).order('EXTRACT (DOY FROM date_of_birth) ASC').first(5)
```

It gives the error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "EXTRACT (DOY FROM (Arel.sql \"DATE(date_of_birth)\")) ASC". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql().
```

What can be done? How can I wrap `date_of_birth` in Arel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the DEPRECATION You can wrap this as follows:

```
.order(Arel.sql('EXTRACT (DOY FROM date_of_birth) ASC'))
```

Or even

```
.order(Arel.sql('EXTRACT (DOY FROM date_of_birth)').asc)
```

However I would take it a step further and go with the following:

```
custom_clause = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('EXTRACT',
  [Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("DOY FROM members.date_of_birth")]
)
```

This will produce the required SQL and can be reused as part of the where clause like so

```
@members = Member
            .where(custom_clause.gteq(next_bdays))
            .order(Arel.sql(custom_clause.to_sql).asc)
            .first(5)
```

Which will produce the following query. (assuming `next_bdays == 123`)

```
SELECT 
  members.* 
FROM 
  members 
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(DOY FROM members.date_of_birth) >= 123  
ORDER BY 
  EXTRACT(DOY FROM members.date_of_birth) ASC
LIMIT 5
```

[Some Raw SQL will be acceptable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1340498d2102423665cc5cfe7be7cdba32c72928/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb#L137) as long as it follows standard column_name or table.column_name syntax [Whitelist can be found here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1340498d2102423665cc5cfe7be7cdba32c72928/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L153) and as always Arel objects will also be supported [Reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1340498d2102423665cc5cfe7be7cdba32c72928/activerecord/lib/arel.rb#L38)